# Local database creation

Tags: sql, database, oracle, connection

I am using oracle sql developer trying to create a new connection. From what i see this connection is needed to create a new database.
The problem is that I receive an error:
The network adapter could not establish the connection

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it in the other way: first create the db, start it, configure the listener for it and then you can connect a sql dev on it.